# How to connect to localhost on a real device in react native on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, networking, server, configuration

I have a server running on localhost:5000 on my desktop, and when I make http requests through my react-native app when running on the iOS simulation to it, it works. However, when I connect to a real device, the http requests don't work. What am I doing wrong? Is there something I have to configure?

Comment: have you tried using your desktop ip address? setting `localhost` wouldnt work for me.

Comment: Well, what can you see in the logs? Can you paste it in your question?

Answer (score 3):

If your are on macOS go to settings -> Wifi / and show more,
on bottom you see "IP address", it's your correct localhost for ios physical device !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer is too late but I ran into a similar situation today and I got it to work by running my node server using the IPv4 of my desktop and then making the request to that IP.

For example, I am running my nodejs development server at `http://192.168.0.135:3000`(local IP of my desktop) instead of `localhost` and then I make the fetch API request from my react-native app to `http://192.168.0.135:3000/`.

Just make sure your nodejs server and your app are on the same local network. My react-native server (metro bundler) is running on a separate PC also in the same wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

localhost in your desktop is not the same ip of the localhost of your device.
Get the ip of your computer by typing ifconfig in a terminal, then replace localhost by this ip, you should type something like that in your device browser:

> 192.168.0.23:5000